# AngularJS deployment to Netlify

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a complete project of angularJS app with backend in nodeJS. I want to deploy it to netlify with complete frontend and backend.

My app starts in commandline with `"npm start"` and in browser `"localhost:8081"`.
Can I deploy it to netlify. Is it possible?

If yes then please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expose your NodeJS API through Netlify, but you can deploy your AngularJS front-end.

Follow this link to do that [Hosting Angular Apps on Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2015/11/10/a-step-by-step-guide-hosting-angular-apps-on-netlify/)